# Trying to shrink dig width when is get to 400

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a div and click event on the div, every click grow the width and height
of the div by 50. and I want

When the div reaches the size of 400, every click will shrink its size by 50.

and when the ball size reaches 100, it again starts to grow

So, with the clicks, div size goes like this:
100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400, 350, 300, 250,  200, 150, 100, 150, 200 ....

Thanks for helpers

**Here is the code**

```
 <div class="ball2" onclick="onBall2Click()">



function onBall2Click() {

            var ball2Size = 100;
            var ball2SizeStep = 50;
            var ball2 = document.querySelector('.ball2');

            //  alert('Ball2');

            ball2Size = ball2Size + ball2SizeStep; // 100 + 50
            ball2.innerText = ball2Size;
            ball2.style.width = ball2Size;
            ball2.style.height = ball2Size;

            if (ball2Size > 400) {
                ball2Size = ball2Size - ball2SizeStep
            }

        }
```

Comment: @reyno  the default size is 100, so when I first click it's reached 150 and stuck on it...

Comment: This is because you need to move the `var ...` lines outside of the function. Otherwise you keep overwriting them

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example snippet that does the trick! Like @kipy said, you need to invert the direction when you reach your thresholds. I've also included a state so you know what the current size and step is.

```js
const MIN_SIZE = 100;
const MAX_SIZE = 400;
const STEP = 50;

const state = {
  currentSize: MIN_SIZE,
  currentStep: STEP
};

const onBall2Click = (e) => {
  const ball = e.target;
  const { currentSize, currentStep } = state;
  const newSize = currentSize + currentStep;
    
  ball.style.width = `${newSize}px`;
  ball.style.height = `${newSize}px`;
  
  state.currentSize = newSize;
  
  if (state.currentSize >= MAX_SIZE || state.currentSize <= MIN_SIZE) {
    state.currentStep = -state.currentStep;
  }
};

const ball = document.querySelector('.ball');
ball.addEventListener('click', onBall2Click);
```

```css
.ball {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="ball"></div>
```